# Redmine as auth backend for another site

Tags: django, redmine

Everyone in our office has a redmine account and so I would like to know if it's possible to use Redmine as an authentication provider.

We create internal websites using django, and rather than having to set up usernames and passwords for each one, for each person, wouldn't it be nicer if I could just click "login using redmine". Just like how on stackoverflow I can click "login with google" which works with OpenID.

Is there any plugin or facility of redmine I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider Redmine OAuth provider plugin.

https://github.com/suer/redmine_oauth_provider

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Redmine Rest API authentication](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Authentication). It allows you to use user/password to authenticate.